# WCF invalidoperationexception

Tags: wcf, linq-to-sql, invalidoperationexception

I encounter this strange problem while using wcf services along with 
L2SQL DAL.
The server is hosted at the localhost and contains an implementation of the correspondent interface. The client is familiar with the interface and occasionally queries the database via the exposed service using tcp transport.
When client runs locally everything's just fine.
But whenever client runs at another machine the 'InvalidOperationException' is thrown in the System.Data.dll (the transport still gets delivered) and over the time the channel enters 'Faulted' state(and transport fails to get delivered).
I feel I'm missing something very basic in my application.
Could anyone please point out possible reasons for such and odd behaviour?

Comment: Did you try to use WCF tracing?

Comment: yes, it's enabled but I can't see anything specific... Anyway, after some additional checking I've figures the problem lies in the specific query or in the way it's treated.

Comment: I think I have found the problem. I was using the parallel update approach which confused the underlying database. Even applying AsOrdered() method hasn't fixed the problem. After rolling back to sequential approach everything seems in order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An exception in the service will cause the channel to enter a Faulted state, if you do not clean up properly. See: http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/erwyn/archive/2006/12/09/WCF-Service-Proxy-Helper.aspx
for how to clean up the proxy when the service fails.

On your problem with L2SQL, looks like you allready found a solution.